# why is there no software downloadable wallet for ETH?

Tags: ether, erc-20, etherscan, myetherwallet, coinbase

There is bitcoin core wallet..which you download on your computer and you have 100% full ownership of your bitcoin BUT etheruem NEVER has anything like this..most of the wallets are either on a website or some company or some service

What happens if these websites, companies and services go burst(i mean history shows this, dont be in denial please)

Please answer below
Thanks

source: https://ethereum.org/wallets/

> What is an Ethereum wallet, and which one should I use?
>
> Wallets are applications that make it easy to hold and send ETH, as well as
>   interact with applications built on Ethereum.
>
> Want to install a wallet? Here are a few options:
>
> MetaMask: browser extension and mobile wallet for iOS and Android
>
> MyCrypto: web-based wallet
>
> TrustWallet: mobile wallet for iOS and Android
>
> MyEtherWallet: client-side wallet
>
> Argent: mobile wallet for iOS and Android, optimized for DeFi
>
> Coinbase Wallet: mobile wallet for iOS and Android
>
> Gnosis Safe: security oriented multi-signature wallet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most (if not all) of the wallets you mentioned are non-custodial, meaning that they do not control your funds. If a service were to go down, you can simply go to another and use your private key there. Funds are stored on the blockchain directly, not on the service itself.

This is different from custodial wallets or services (e.g. Coinbase). Those services control your private keys, so you don't have full control over your funds. If one of those services goes offline, you do lose access to your funds.

MyCrypto has a desktop version that you can download if you don't want to rely on a website. You can download it from here: https://download.mycrypto.com. It works fully offline too, and you can use it with your own Ethereum node if preferred.